# Parse date format MM,dd,yy to yyyy-MM-dd in VB

Tags: vb.net, parsing, datetime, format

pretty self explanatory.

Here's what I've tried:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(worksheet.Range("B" & i).Value().ToString(), "MM,dd,yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

where `worksheet.Range("B" & i).Value().ToString()` is "04,13,15" (the Excel default for dates it looks like)

ERROR:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might want to check that the cell actually contains `"04,13,15"` meaning a string.  The cell could actually contain a valid, standard date value which is simply formatted to display that way (in which case it may not need to be parsed at all).

Comment: Remove this part `worksheet.Range("B" & i).Value().ToString()` and replace it with `"04,13,15"` and then check it out, it worked fine with me.

Comment: @Plutonix How do you propose I do this given that it is actually in date format? (I checked the Excel file it's coming from, and it is formatted as a date that way.) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with:

```
 Format(worksheet.Range("B" & i).Value(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

outputs

```
 2015-04-13
```

Comment: So it appears that Plutonix and Muhammad were correct. The value in the worksheet in a date and not a string.